# Image scroller with jQuery that supports image pre-caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, image-gallery, scroller

A good example of what I need to implement can be seen at http://www.gojee.com There, different images of food are scrolled effectively, image to image with javascript, and the sript supports next image pre-caching. Their JS is obfuscated and minimized, so I can't just "look" how they have implemented it.

Can anyone point to a jQuery plugin that allows to "page" images with embedded pre-caching of a next image, but without a knowledge of an entire list like jQuery Tools "Scrollable" control?

Comment: jsbeautifier.com and a little work and you're done :)

Comment: Thanks. Although minification is easy to work around - obfuscation is impossible to overcome, since the logical meanings of the variables are lost when they are called a,b,c.

Comment: Check this question out on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350993/using-jquery-loop-to-alternate-image-scr/11351108#comment14950249_11351108

Comment: Fading in and out is a simplest task. I need sliding. Thanks anyway.