# Using JQuery loop to alternate image scr

Tags: jquery, image, loops, src

Okay so I have an image (id = "slideshow") in my content section of my site. I'm trying to create a loop that alternates the image src using JQuery. Here is the code I have so far. It seems to loop through but the only src change that it shows is the last one. As a result glossy.jpg is the only image I see. I know it must be working to some extent seeing as glossy.jpg is not the original src that I have set. Once I get each picture to show I'll tidy up the rest of the code. Any answers are much appreciated =)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    $("#slideshow").attr("src", "Images/image1.jpg").fadeTo(3000, 1.00);
    $("#slideshow").fadeTo("slow", 0.00);
    $("#slideshow").attr("src", "Images/image2.jpg").fadeTo(3000, 1.00);
    $("#slideshow").fadeTo("slow", 0.00);
    $("#slideshow").attr("src", "Images/glossy1.jpg").fadeTo(3000, 1.00);
    $("#slideshow").fadeTo("slow", 0.00);
    }
    });
```

Comment: in your code above the loop is doing nothing but running that same block of code over and over. It's running those 3 processes at the same time not one after the other.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I haven't done much coding with JQuery. However I don't understand why the code doesn't execute line by line within the loop. Am I making some very basic mistake here? :/

Comment: You are not telling it to wait.  So it just runs them all concurrently (x100).  The answer below is the way to do it.  Store the images in an array and then loop through them over set intervals.

Comment: @BarryDelaney The code below is fully functional and can be directly employed :)

Comment: So each line doesn't wait for the previous to finish? Would I need to use .delay()? Yes that code worked perfectly, I'm just interested to know why my code is so wrong as there must be something fundamental I'm not getting.

Comment: The issue is you are not iterating through anything on your loop. You are running the same block of code 100x. A for loop like that is often used to iterate through a numbered set of things (i.e. "image"+i+".jpg") So this would give you image1.jpg,  image2.jpg....image100.jpg. Where i is the counter number. I hope this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code for an image rota tor that you are making.

```
var images = new Array ('test1.png', 'test2.png', 'test3.png');
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('#myImage').fadeOut('fast', function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function()
    {
      if (index == images.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval (rotateImage, 2500);
});
```

And this would be the HTML

```
<div id="test">
  <img id="myImage" src="test1.png" alt="image test" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
</div>
```

Since you could utilize arrays while storing URL's into them and then so the same rotation using `setInterval()` function.

Referance : [www.burnmind.com](http://www.burnmind.com/howto/how-to-create-a-simple-automatic-image-rotator-using-jquery)

Comment: @BarryDelaney Then I guess u would accept my answer :) .... but anyways this is the way you should Iterate.SInce in the last sample every time loop was called every image was reattributed. :)

Comment: Yup I gave you the green tick =) Thanks very much, I will be sure to take that advice on board.